# 1950s-1979 young adult novel about a boy traveling through world which turns out to be a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, young-adult, spaceship

I remember reading this book as a kid. It was a hard-cover book with a picture of an alien jumping up and down or dancing in the bottom right-hand corner of the cover. It was definitely geared toward young adults or children. A chapter book.

The protagonist is a boy who travels beyond the walls of his home. Eventually he learns his home is at the center of a giant spaceship through which he has been traveling through all its layers. I believe the alien creature from the cover was his companion and had a quirky, funny personality. I also remember the boy eating cube-shaped food that arrives automatically and not knowing where it comes from until he travels to one of the other “worlds” (layers of the ship) and sees that food is produced and sent to them from another place.

Comment: None of the answers to [Young man discovers his home “world” is a spaceship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172833/young-man-discovers-his-home-world-is-a-spaceship) match?

Comment: This may be an obvious question, but was this in English?

Comment: It was in English, yes.

Comment: None of the answers to the thread about “young man discovers his home “world” is a spaceship match what I am looking for. I did look up each of those books, but none sound familiar or have the alien companion I remember.

Comment: A long time ago, there was a question posted on here asking for help finding what might be the same old story about a teenage boy on a pilgrimage inside what turned out to be a generation ship. At the time, I didn't know the answer. Later, I stumbled across an old SF novel that might have been it. Now I can't remember the title of that novel. I think I found a copy on OpenLibrary.org, but it appears that I can't bring up a list of all the books on that site that I've previously "checked out" to read.

Comment: Thank you for trying, Lorendiac!

Answer (score 5):

*The World and Thorin* by Damon Knight. Some similar passing themes of a boy travelling through different layers in a generation ship, eating cube food, finding an AI computer box. Does the cover strike a bell?

[image: Cover]

Comment: No alien companion in that one, although it is a good book. I asked after it at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55178/fantasy-piece-involving-different-worlds-and-a-crippled-protagonist

Comment: It doesn’t strike a bell, but it seems too much of a coincidence that the storyline is so similar. Maybe my memory is failing me. I’ll have to get this one and read it. And I can ask my dad if he has seen this book before because he is the one who owned the book I remember. He hasn’t remembered it or found it yet though. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thorin’s nickname was flea because he had one leg longer slightly by birth than the other and had a bit of a hopping walk, if that is the hopping connection. And companion was a magic box he finds that talked to him... which was an AI computer for the ship.